# Should I include my research interests in my CV? How?

Tags: publications, research-process, cv

I don't have any publications yet and I never coauthored a paper.  My question is, should I put in my CV the list of publications I have read (publications of other authors, I mean) and list them under "Read publications" or it is meaningless?

Comment: After your Educational qualification, mention a section called "Research Interests". It should work. Don't be too specific on the areas.

Answer (score 8):

In my opinion this is a very bad idea. If I would get such a CV I would wonder why it's in there and thoughts are:

- There are no real achievements so this was put in
- The author thinks reading papers is an achievement or at least something special
- The author read only a few papers (and if you are interested in a topic this list should have several pages)

All those points doesn't make you look very good. I wouldn't reply to that, and to be honest, think it's a bad joke.

Comment: It depends on the area and the level of OP. If he is applying for grad school in, say, mathematics, it is not expected of him to have any papers written. On top of that, reading throughly 20+ articles is nearly impossible for an undergrad, and would raise suspicion (unless he is the next Tao, Scholze,...)

Answer (score 5):

I do not think it is common nor useful to put publications of others on your CV, because people read a lot - especially in the scientific world - and it therefore at most shows your interests. Therefore, if you want to show what your interests are, you can put it under **interests**. If you want to show that you have done work around that subject you could mention it as a **project**.

If you write the CV for a potential PhD position for example, you could **cite** the papers you have read in your motivation letter explaining about your interest and/or proposed research.